# Let $\alpha= f\,dx_1 \wedge \cdots\wedge dx_n$; where $f$ is continuous on $A$. Show that $\int_ \Phi \alpha =\int_ \Phi f$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}_k$ be a rectangle (or box), and let $\Phi:A\to\mathbb{R}_k$, be the identity mapping.

Let $\alpha= f \, dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$; where $f$ is continuous on $A$.

Show that

$$\int_ \Phi \alpha =\int_ \Phi f$$

I'm not sure what the formal way to proceed is, if we just go back to the formal definitions of $\alpha(\Phi)$ and $f(\Phi)$ I know what to do in the case of $\alpha$ but I'm not sure what to do for $f$ because it's a $0$-form.

So by looking at the definition, there is no jacobian to calculate for $f$ and for $\alpha$ the jacobian has to be one because we have an identity mapping? I'm not sure how to write this properly.

Thank you for your help as always!

Comment: $\int_\Phi f$ is $\int_A f$ ?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla The notation simply means that one integrates over the "surface" parametrized by the given map.

Comment: Actually, I think Martin is right: this problem is clearly to compare the definition of "surface integral" of a differential form proportional to a function with the existing definition of the integral of a function, when the surface is a set on which a function can usually be integrated.  BTW: I think the $n$ in your differential form needs to be $k$.

Comment: I think you really want $\int_{A}f$ where the integral is taken in the measure theoretic sense. The LHS of the equation should refer to evaluation of the cochain $\alpha$ on the chain $\Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

According to Baby Rudin,
$$\int_\Phi\alpha=\int_A (f\circ\Phi)\cdot\det D\Phi.$$

In this case ($\Phi=Id$),
$$\int_\Phi\alpha=\int_A f.$$